# How to avoid multiple definition of C variable?

Tags: c, variables, c-preprocessor

I'm getting an error with multiple definition of a **C** variable I have declared in my header and am using in my source file.

In my header file I have:

```
//Number of jobs in the job list
extern int numberOfJobs;
```

In my source file I have used numberOfJobs in multiple functions calls.

I also have a pre-process directives at the top of my header file.

```
#ifndef _JOBS_GROUP_H_
#define _JOBS_GROUP_H_
```

and end it with

```
#endif
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?  I'm fairly new to **C**.

Comment: You should post your code here to see what's happening

Comment: If it is extern, then you should also post the code where it was in fact declared...

Comment: @K You meant "defined". It's declared *right here.*

Comment: You should also post the error message (copy-and-paste it, don't re-type or summarize).

Comment: What you've shown is looks correct. You should have a definition of `numberOfJobs` in exactly one `.c` file. The `extern` declaration in your `.h` should appear exactly once in each translation unit that refers to it; the include guards should handle that. The definition needs to appear exactly once in your entire program. If at all possible, write a small program (perhaps 3 files of a few lines each) that reproduces the problem, and show us those source files in your question, along with the compiler command you're using and the exact error message.

Comment: Something that's not relevant to your problem: Don't define identifiers starting with an underscore, particularly if it's followed by another underscore or by an uppercase letter. Such identifiers are reserved to the implementation. `#ifdef H_JOBS_GROUP` would be better. (That's unlikely to cause a visible problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why I was getting multiple definition errors/undefined reference errors to my extern variables.

First of all import "jobsgroup.h" and  makes a difference in which error I got.  I got multiple definition error when importing with the quotes, but got undefined reference error when using the <>.  You use "" for when the file is in the same directory and <> if the file is in an include folder.  My header file was in an include folder, so using <> is more preferable in my case.

Now the real solution to this problem was I thought by defining my variable in my init function was defining the extern variable.  However, to define the extern variable, you have to declare it above your functions in your source file like so:

int numberOfJobs;

This solved all of my errors.  Thank you guys for trying to help me out.